# Keeping png transperancy using a jQuery Lights Out effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, light

On my page I have implemented a basic lights out effect from this source here:
http://www.emanueleferonato.com/stuff/lightsoff/

I would like a PNG image to be the button that 'switches the lights on' however the image has a persistent white box from the div it's in. Is it possible for just the PNG image to sit above the black layer in the lights out effect?

My test is at this url:
http://www.voyagedesign.net/illuminatetests/logolightsout.html

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from this CSS:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   background-color: #F6F6F4;
}
```

Either remove that background-color attribute or override it:

```
#logo > img {
    background-color: initial;
}
```

or:

```
#logo > img {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The override didn't seem to work however when I removed the background color from the "*" and moved to "body" it seems to work fine. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Got another solution for you.

What i did is created a round div and placed your logo image as background. This seems to do the job.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DApVV/)**

HTML

```
<div id="logo"></div>
```

CSS

```
#logo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:130px;
    width:130px;
    -moz-border-radius:130px;
    -webkit-border-radius:130px;
    padding:35px;
    text-align:center;
    color:white;
    background-image: url(http://www.voyagedesign.net/illuminatetests/BMW_logo.png);
    position:relative;
    z-index:50;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However the BMW logo was just a placeholder (the real one isn't a cirle) as I didn't want to post the final logo as it isn't mine. Just being careful lol. Thank you again for your answer though!